# ebay HTTPS 12030 with WinHttpOpenRequest

Tags: asynchronous, https

since two years I access the ebay trading api with a C++ program. Since a few days I get lots of HTTPS errors 12030. Do I have to install a new certificate or something like this?
Sometimes only a small 40kB XML is sent, a few times the respond is empty. Using WIN10 and Server 2019. Both show this error since a few days.

WinHttpOpenRequest( conndata.m_hConnect, method, address,
NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH + WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

Right now I send requests with an error in the response again. I use MS HTTP API async.

Answer (score 0):

It is only the activation of TLS 1.1 and 1.2. On my Win 10 and Server 2019 Standard machines are a few registry keys missing.

See here:

[Defining protocols](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/topic/update-zum-aktivieren-von-tls-1-1-und-tls-1-2-als-sichere-standardprotokolle-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392)

and here

[Enable protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client)